# Syntax analysis and syntax tree

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, lexical-analysis, abstract-syntax-tree

I am implementing a compiler for a school class and I have some problems on how to proceed.
Lexical analysis is already made. Lexical analysis to me is that I have a function that returns token objects and also prints some errors that can be inspected during lexical analysis.

The token holds id, string (if the current id is a string, if not it is null), number (if the token is a number, if not it is null) and the line where the token found.

I want to make the syntax analysis but i am not sure if i have to generate a syntax tree during this procedure. I am sure that this will be necessary while generating intermediate code but the teacher leaves the decision to us.

So to end. The teacher want us to understand that it is necessary?
If it is really necessary what is the best way to construct a syntax tree?
Also am i missing something that will cause me trouble in later stages?

Comment: Well, one-pass compilers without elaborate intermediate representations are certainly possible. But it depends on the language and the desired functionality whether it's *viable*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, your syntax analysis will end up being some form of a [finite-state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). The result of this process is usually an AST; the syntax analysis seems somewhat pointless if you don't store the result of it somewhere.

While there are [many different well-known and established algorithms for creating the state tables and for implementing the actual processor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser#Types_of_parser), you might want to start thinking like the compiler and define your states by hand (which is feasible for really simple languages):

- At the very beginning, what tokens would be acceptable? (Start state)
- Each token will lead you to another state and possibly have you perform an operation to consolidate your tokens into an abstract syntax tree. (State transitions)
- I suggest to treat "End of file" as a special token returned by the tokenizer, so that your syntax analysis doesn't need any special code to handle the end of file (just normal state transition dealing with the EOF token).

Note that, instead of using tables, you can also use functions to represent your states.

What is the language you're trying to implement?

Comment: I am treating the end of file as a token but i decided that it will not be needed in later stages. As a result I made a function that runs the lexer and returns a token until we reach end of file. The language I am trying to implement is a c-like language.

Comment: My advice is to keep the EOF token, because your state machine will need it in order to avoid custom checks for EOF. Let's assume we parse something like that: `void A() { return 1; }` - how does the syntax analysis know what state to switch to ("accept", e.g. finished parsing successfully) after the `}` has been processed? Trust me, you don't want to add `if (IsEOF)` kind of code everywhere - simplify your design by avoiding special cases and just treat this like a normal token.

Comment: I did it like this so if a function asks for the next token and this token is null i will just exit the program.

Comment: You'll find out soon that exiting on EOF/null is not appropriate, because your parser will need to support some form of recursion (e.g. match `{` and `}` even if they are nested etc.), and you will very likely have multiple states on the stack which need to be "finalized" when EOF is reached. As I said, the less specialized code you introduce the easier and cleaner your code will become.

Comment: What is the point of trying to look for example `}` as you say if we reached EOF?

Comment: Well, if you reach EOF before the closing `}` then you got a syntax error. And assuming that `}` is in the token stream, after it you could either have some whitespace, some comment, another type or function definition, or an EOF.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5179/discussion-between-lucero-and-marcus-hatchenson)